# Deactivate the TOMCAT security of a Spring Boot application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

Hello I am using Spring Boot 2.4.3

My application is a Maven multi module application and is composed of Angular/Spring Boot/Spring Security techno. I used the following tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_the_login_page_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_ii
by doing a >mvn clean package on my parent module, I create a jar that I run with java -jar backend-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. The angular front that is embedded functions well, I tested it.

Normally when I launch Spring Boot, it should give me a password corresponding to the "user" identifier as shown in the following picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLT2o.png)

But when I launch my Spring Boot there is no password displayed. So I end up with an authentication window that asks me for a user and a password

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oBIh.png)

I think that’s the security of the TOMCAT server in Spring Boot. The ideal would be to disable this security and I don’t know how. I did a lot of work without finding

I tried to add the following lines in application.properties without success

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration

security.user.name=user
security.user.password=password

spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=password

security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled =false
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception
    {
     security.httpBasic().disable();
    }
}
```

But I can only see the index.html page displayed. the application does not take into account the angular routes